# How to make pdfsam work in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: openjdk, pdfsam

I `apt-get install pdfsam` in 16.04. It doesn't work with the OpenJDK 9 (preinstalled). Author's site says it works with JDK8. So i did:

```
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

That didn't work ,so i tried:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Still nothing. Nada. Any ideas what i did wrong?

Comment: What happens when you open a terminal window and run `pdfsam`? Please edit your post to include any messages that appear.

Comment: Make sure you have openjfx installed as well, PDFsam requires Java8 with JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Java versions installed, you can set the version used by default.

Use the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

I had no desire to change the system default so the fix to make pdfsam run is simply to add to your home bin directory a shell script which starts it using the the right Java flavor. Here is what I did:

```
$ cat ~/bin/pdfsam
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export JAVACMD=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

/usr/bin/pdfsam
```

and all works fine thereafter. Even my menu shortcut works fine which pleased me (clearly did not point at the /usr/bin/pdfsam script).